# What's the output voltage of this transformer?

Tags: transformer

Input is 120VAC. Let's say its a step down with a ratio of 10:1. Is the primary voltage 120V or 240V?

[image]

Comment: Yes indeed it is. In parallel as drawn : 120V. In series : 240V. So, yes it is 120V or 240V.

Comment: Didn't ask any yes or no questions

Comment: Maybe not, but the question title is about the output voltage and the question body is about the primary voltage after stating what the primary voltage is. It's a little garbled.

Comment: @kefffin, you have asked ten questions on the site, got answers to eight and the answers I've checked look good but you have accepted none. If you are not aware there is an "accept" button beside each answer and you should upvote and accept good answers as some sort of thanks for those who have given of their time to help educate you.

Answer (score 6):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMauSu.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Parallel and series connection of primaries.*

> Input is 120VAC.

Very often two primary windings are supplied. Typically these are 120 V windings which allows for use on 120 V supplies when wired in parallel as shown in Figure 1a and on 240 V supplies when wired in series as shown in Figure 1b.

This arrangement is convenient for devices which are sold worldwide as the input voltage can be switch selectable.

> Let's say its a step down with a ratio of 10:1. Is the primary voltage 120V or 240V?

The drawing shows (with errors) that the secondaries are wire to give 18-0-18 V if the centre-tap is grounded or 0 - 36 V from end to end. The ratio between each primary and secondary is 120:18 = 20:3.

Wiring in series doubles the number of primary turns and hence the input voltage rating. Wiring in parallel doubles the cross-sectional area of the turns and hence the current handling capacity. Each coil can transfer the same amount of power so in either configuration (a) or (b) above the total maximum load is the same.

The transformer core flux is determined by the total number of ampere-turns in the primaries. It can't tell whether they have been produced by series or parallel connection of the coils.

Answer (score 3):

There are two primaries in parallel connected to the input voltage.

With this kind of transformer you connect the primaries in parallel (in phase) for 120VAC and in series (adding) for 240VAC.

---

Edit:
You *could* supply the transformer from a single primary coil and leave the other one disconnected, but the maximum output would be somewhat reduced. With the transformer windings paralleled the current in each is halved and the total \$I^2R\$ losses are also halved compared to using just one winding.

Sometimes a tap is used, which is effectively the same. You leave the 240V tap flapping in the breeze (and it really does have 240V on it relative to the N when the primary is energized with 120VAC). To absolutely optimize that kind of transformer you would use heavier copper wire for the half that is to be used on 120VAC. I've only seen that done by very persnickety designers, often they just use the same wire gauge. It's not as optimized because that copper that is doing nothing when powered from 120VAC could be used to reduce the losses.

In the case of two primaries it's optimal in terms of use of the iron and copper, but involves more connections (and involves more complex switching arrangement to change from 120 to 240VAC).

There are some types of cores and split bobbins where having two primaries is magnetically better (photo from Digikey):
[image]

Bottom line is that it's all about optimizing the transformer design.

Most of this is no longer important since many items have "universal" supplies that will work from the puniest sagging Japanese 50/60Hz 100VAC nominal to 240VAC 50 or 60Hz with a healthy overvoltage on too.

Comment: I was thinking surely they must add, but I guess not. You're not necessarily doubling the amount of coils there would "normally" be in this configuration. What is the point of this used in the configuration above? Why not use something with a single primary winding?

Comment: See edit- dual voltage transformers involve some compromises.